# How to read/write a collection of objects as json

Tags: ruby, json

I have a collection of User classes that I want to save as a json file.

```
users = []
users << User.new('john', 'smith', 55)

File.open("users.json", "w") do |f|
  f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(users)
end
```

The problem is the User isn't being JSON'ified, it is saving to the file like:

```
[
  "#<User:0x000000101010eff40>",
  ..
]
```

Also, how will I read this json file back into a collection?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your users variable is still an array of ActiveRecord objects. You need to convert them into json.

```
users = []
users << User.new('john', 'smith', 55)

File.open("users.json", "w") do |f|
  f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(users.to_json)
end
```

Comment: This didn't work, I removed the JSON.pretty_generate and I still see the "#<User:0x000000101010eff40>" in my json file.  (pretty print didn't work either)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `users.to_json` to convert the object into json string.

To read this json file back to object, you can read the string from file and use `JSON.parse(str)` where `str` is the string read. This will return you the collection of user object as a hash.